# Unable to install package after enabling Allow Search on custom object

Tags: managed-package

In our package, we enabled `Allow Search` (in package XML it is `enableSearch`) for 2 custom objects. Both are child objects, one in master detail and other is in lookup relationship.

[Indexing progress](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008fsmQAA) is completed in custom objects:
[image]

--

Now, the beta package from our current packaging org and managed release from our older patch org is successfully build. We get following error in failure email:

> entity type {Custom Object API Name} does not support search

Issue is that it's not allowing us to install new version of the package without enabling those settings.

Ideally the package would be upgraded without any manual changes. Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no workaround, this becomes a pre-installation step for the package.

Unless someone has a better solution, closing the question with this as an answer.